# get object name from queryset in template

Tags: django, jinja2

How can I get object from queryset by id manualy in template?

**context_prosessors.py**

```
from products.models import Category


def cat_sidebar(request):
    sidebar_category = Category.objects.all()
    return {'cat_sidebar': sidebar_category}
```

**Template**

```
<h2 class="card-title text-white title">
    {{cat_sidebar.sub_category.get(id = 5).name}}
</h2>
```

Comment: This question is completely impossible to answer as you haven't provided any information. Please show your template, views and models, and describe exactly what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution (based on a **custom tag**):

What you are looking for is a template tag. Go into the products app directory add these files:

```
templatetags
templatetags/__init__.py
templatetags/tags.py
```

The **templatetags/tags.py** file:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_name(cat_sidebar, id):
    return cat_sidebar.get(id=id).name
```

The template part, with our tag call:

```
{% load tags %}

<h2 class="card-title text-white title">
    {{get_name cat_sidebar 5}}
</h2>
```

For more info refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a parameter to a function in the templates. This is not allowed.

```
cat_sidebar.sub_category.get(id = 5).name
```

There is a work around with **template tags** about which you can read in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) but I would suggest you to do this operation in the view and then send it to the template using context as it is faster to do operations in the view than in template.

**Template Tag Solution**

*Note - It is only if you have to do it and I don't suggest this.*

Add **templatetags** and its contents in your project.

```
yourapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        mytags.py
    views.py
```

The **__init__.py** can be empty. Your **mytags.py** file will have something like this

```
from django import template
from ..models import Category  # Import Category here. Yours might differ

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def get_category_by_id(id):
    category = Category.objects.get(id=id)
    return category
```

Now the template will look something like this

```
{% load mytags %}
{% get_category_by_id 5 %}
```

**Suggested Solution:**

The view will look something like this.

```
def cat_sidebar(request):
    sidebar_category = Category.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.get(id = 5)

    return {'cat_sidebar': sidebar_category, 'category': category}
```

And template becomes

```
<h2 class="card-title text-white title">
    {{ category.name }}
</h2>
```